# the view using windows.location = "some url" changes, but the elements (objects) are from the old url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

To redirect to an URL on PhoneGap on iOS i'm using this code in javascript

```
function pedirTaxi(){
    var direccion =  $('#txtDireccion').val();
    alert(direccion);
    window.location.href = "loading.html";
    cambiarBar();
    ...
}

function cambiarBar(){
    var ajaxs = 100;
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
    ...
}
```

And it stills shows the old url which is index.html. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong, I've tried everything, using jquery (which is still javascript) and using window.location.replace, or .assign, i'm really stuck.

The html that calls the function pedirTaxi(), is in index.html and is the following one:

```
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pedirTaxi()">
            pedir taxi
    </button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: any more infomation? and can you report something in you developer tool, for example loading.html will get a redirect because it is not found or etc.? More info will be helpful for us to understand

Comment: Because i'm using phonegap on XCode I don't really have too much information, for debug or in console. But loading.html does load, it is found, but the elements, doesn't change, it keeps index.html elements. I edit the question, I know it is little information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use window.open instead of window.location.href that is just a property.

If you want to see what's happens in your application, you can open it with chrome with the disable web security option and the debug mode (cmd + alt + j)